# Display regions and cities with job offers from that

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have tables: Country, City, Region and Joboffers. Mt relationships look like this:
Country with Region
City with Region and Joboffers
I want to display regions (remmember that Region and Joboffer is in relationship so I want to create loop inside loop in order to display regions and cities from that)
but only if contain joboffers. Look at this query

```
    $regions = Region::where('country_id', $id)->whereHas('jobs', function($query) {
        return $query->whereHas('cities', function($quesry){
            return $quesry->where('active', 1);
        });
    })->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

I'll show all models

```
//Country
    public function regions(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Regions");
    }
    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\City");
    }
//Region
    public function country(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
    }
    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
    public function jobs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Joboffer');
    }
//City
    public function region(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
    }
    public function jobs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Joboffer');
    }
//Joboffer
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'city_id', 'region_id', 'description', 'phone', 'photo', 'user_id', 'active'];
    public function city(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
    public function region(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

My query doesn't work. It display correctly regions but it display all cities from that. Not only with active offers. Howw can I solve my problem?

### @Edit

My controller's method look like this

```
public function checkCitiesFromRegion($id){
    $regions = Region::with('cities.jobs')->where('country_id', $id)->whereHas('cities', function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('jobs', function ($quesry) {
            $quesry->where('active', 1);
        });
    })->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
    foreach($regions as $region){
        echo $region->name . '<br>';
        foreach($region->cities as $city){
            echo $city->name;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't use view becouse I wanted to test this code.

Comment: your `Region` and `City` are many to many relationships right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to fetch all regions from a given country that have cities with active job offers, You can do something like this:

```
$regions = Region::where('country_id', $id)->whereHas('cities', function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('jobs', function ($quesry) {
        $quesry->where('active', 1);
    });
});
```

If you will want to eager load all the relationships data in the same query you could chain the `with()` method to your query:

```
$regions = Region::with('cities.jobs')->where('country_id', $id)->whereHas('cities', function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('jobs', function ($quesry) {
        $quesry->where('active', 1);
    });
});
```

Note: No need to add the return statement to your `whereHas()` queries.

**@Edit**

With your edit, where you show your controller code I now understand whats happening.

You are retrieving all Regions that have cities with active job offers, but when you run your for each loop eloquent automatically loads all cities for that region (event the ones with no active job offers), that's why you are getting this result, so we must retrieve all regions that have cities with active job offers and only load those cities into it's region. Something like this should work:

```
$regions = Region::with(['cities' => function($query) {
        $query->with(['jobs' => function ($quesry) {
            $quesry->where('active', 1);
        }])->whereHas('jobs', function ($quesry) {
            $quesry->where('active', 1)
        });
    }])->where('country_id', $id)->whereHas('cities', function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('jobs', function ($quesry) {
        $quesry->where('active', 1);
    })->get();
});
```

Haven't tested but that should work. This will load only the cities that have active jobs and the active jobs of each region that has cities with active job offers.

Hope that makes sense .

Comment: Problem is this same. It display all cities from regions but I want to display only cities where is some job offer.

Comment: Then there must be something else wrong, can you share all your controller & front end code, where you loop through the collection? or have you tried dumping the result of `$regions`?

Comment: You forget about ->get() at the end of query. I add that (it doesn;t work without it) but problem is this same. It display all cities from regions.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about the `get()` to fetch the data. That's weird that it gives you the same result, maybe there is an issue where it reloads the relationships in your foreach. Have you tried dumping `$regions` before the foreach loop to see the results?

Comment: I updated my answer again, I added `->whereHas('jobs', function ($quesry) {
                $quesry->where('active', 1)
            })` to the `with('cities')` sub query.

Comment: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'regions.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'cities' where 'regions'.'id' = 'cities'.'region_id' and exists (select * from 'joboffers' where 'cities'.'id' = 'joboffers'.'city_id' and 'active' = 1))
`